# PHP : Can I affect a type when declaration of variable in class?

Tags: php, variables, object

I would declare a private var in my class with a specific type like this :

```
class MyClass
{
    private (int) $myvar;
    private (MyObject) $instance;

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->myvar = 2;
        $this->instance = new MyObject;
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work and it seems there is no way to do what I want.

Comment: AFAIK "But it doesn't work and it seems there is no way to do what I want." - yes

Comment: no, php is loosely typed, you cannot do that. You can have type hinting for function parameters, but even then you cannot hint at scalar types

Answer (score 2):

No need of type Casting. do like this

```
class MyClass
{
    private $myvar;
    private $instance;

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->myvar = 2;
        $this->instance = new MyObject;
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually there is ```int``` in PHP. You can for example ```function ($val) { $someVar = (int) $val; // make sure $someVar is Integer }``` See [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php)

Comment: Exactly i meant for data type declaration, because till now i have simply assigned value to some variables or have directly created objects.so i have edited my answer and many thanks for your info.